# FME Console for testing

Tags: fme-form

I am using FME workbench 2018.1. I am working on a model where i have to apply lots of string operations on different feature classes and then merge them into one. I want to know if there is any console area where i can quickly test the function and see the output rather then running the whole FME again and again. I have been using inspector and logger but i am wondering if there is a console in FME.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use Feature Caching, introduced in FME 2018. This function caches all features at every transformer. This way you can run the proces from a specific transformer.

To enable Feature Caching click "Run", "Run With Feature Caching".
[image: Run With Feature Caching]

After a full run you can click a transformer and hit "Run From This".
[image: Run From This]

A few additions:

- This can use a lot of temp disk space as there will be a lot of caching.
- Because all the read / write actions the performance might be slower.
- To overcome previous issues, transformers in closed bookmarks will not be cached separately, only at the bookmark output.
- In FME 2019 the "Run Workspace" (F5) button is defaulted to run with cached features, to re-run completely fresh use CTRL-F5. This works far more intuitive.

Also see this [blog post](https://www.safe.com/blog/2018/05/caching-data-fme-evangelist174/) and this [article](https://knowledge.safe.com/articles/79739/feature-caching-and-performance.html).

Answer (score 1):

Feature Caching (as noted in another answer) is a good way to go here. Also use a Sampler or limit the number of features being read, as often you'll only want to test one or two features to ensure something is working, not the whole source dataset.

Also, if your transformations use regex then FME has a regex editor with built in tests. Access it through Open Regex Editor, wherever that is available:

[image]

Then you have a dialog in which to test expressions:

[image]

DateTime transformers have a similar dialog for testing expressions.